# Couldn't find OrderInstruction in ActionMailer.deliver_later, but the object exists in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm sending some emails about a notification on an update of an `Order`. The order has many `OrderInstructions`, and for each `OrderInstruction` created, I send an email with all the related info.

Here's how I'm sending the emails for each order instruction:

```
UserMailer.order_updated(order_instruction.id).deliver_later
```

This gets called after the `order_instruction` is created, some steps before the email gets sent. The mailer method checks that the order instruction exists:

```
def order_updated(order_instruction_id):
    order_instruction = OrderInstruction.find_by(id: order_instruction_id)
    return if order_instruction.nil?
    ...
end
```

My problem is that this is not sending the email, because it doesn't find the `order_instruction`, but if I call the mailer using a small delay:

```
UserMailer.order_updated(order_instruction.id).deliver_later(wait: 5.seconds)
```

It works just fine.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to have ActionMailer retry after some time if I raise an error? Or alternatively, have ActionMailer wait some time for all emails being sent, so that this doesn't have to be fixed with every occurrence of this.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to put a stop debug (using binding.pry for example) just before calling `UserMailer.order_updated(order_instruction.id).deliver_later` to check if object exist in database.

Maybe you're calling the mailer inside an ActiveRecord Transaction and changes aren't committed yet.

Comment: It seems that's the case. Is there a solution for this, other than setting the delay manually for each email sent during a transaction? What if the transaction takes more time than the delay I set?

Comment: Maybe you can move email generation to a callback or use this gem https://github.com/grosser/ar_after_transaction